# org.hibernate.boot.MappingNotFoundException: Mapping (RESOURCE) not found

Tags: java, hibernate

I have been trying my hand to implement hibernate using a small example.

Below is my hibernate.config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="connection.driver_class">
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
</property>
<property name="connection.url">
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc
</property>
<property name="connection.username">root</property>
<property name="connection.password"></property>
<property name="dialect">
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<mapping
resource="HibernateExample/src/HibernateExposed/Resource/Person.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When running the code I am getting error org.hibernate.boot.MappingNotFoundException: Mapping (RESOURCE) not found.

I tried replacing mapping as below

```
<mapping
resource="Resource/Person.hbm.xml"/>
```

and also tried to keep the mapping xml at same location as hibernate.config.xml.

```
<mapping
resource="Person.hbm.xml"/>
```

Under none of above mentioned cases, code can find my Person.hbm.xml.

My folder structure looks as below

[image]

I looked at all other answers for this error on Stackoverflow but none of the approaches resolved this issue. Any help is highly appreciated. Also, is there any approach to debug this further to granular level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, put `hibernate.cfg.xml` in the root of `src` folder.

And use

```
<mapping resource="HibernateExposed/Person.hbm.xml"/>
```

Hibernate loads all those files using `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(resourcePath)`  `resourcePath` — is the path to the file

`ClassLoader` tries to get access to the files in the root of `bin` or `build` folder in the IDE, or root of `jar`, or root of `war/WEB-INF/classes/` for web-applications. Those all are the root of the class path.

`bin` is a folder where Eclipse compiles your files. The root of `src` folder is compiled to the root of `bin` folder. You can check it.

For an example

`configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")` — `bin/hibernate.cfg.xml` `configure("xxx/hibernate.cfg.xml")` — `bin/xxx/hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
 <mapping resource="HibernateExposed/Person.hbm.xml"/>
```

corresponds `bin/HibernateExposed/Person.hbm.xml`

A path should be without the leading `/` for a `ClassLoader`. Hibernate tries to delete the leading `/`.

A path like this is valid too

```
<mapping resource="/HibernateExposed/Person.hbm.xml"/>
```

**Update**

You can specify path to the `hibernate.cfg.xml`, if you don't want to have it in the root

`new Configuration().configure("HibernateExposed/hibernate.cfg.xml")`

if you use

`new Configuration().configure()`

it should be in the root of the class path.

Comment: If I put hibernate.cfg.xml at the src folder, I get error  org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource. Anyways, hibernate.cfg.xml should be present at the root of classpath right? In my case, the class(Person) is created under HibernateExposed(package), so its location should not be a problem. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: After making changes to configure(hibernate.cfg.xml), it worked. I have been stuck with this problem for almost last 6 hours. Thanks for the explaination!

Comment: @bestrahul21 I update. Check your build folder. Sometimes Eclipse doesn't clean it. You need to choose clean from a menu.

Comment: @bestrahul21 Because Eclipse doesn't rebuild a project after you change a file location.

Answer (score 0):

none of this worked for me, then I tried this:-

(replace this method in FactoryConfiguration singleton Class)

```
private FactoryConfiguration() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(***Class Name***.class);
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    }
```