# Get file path - Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to create a session factory for hibernate, but by default it looks for "hibernate.cfg.xml" file. **I did not create this file.** All hibernate config is in "applicationContext.xml" file of Spring MVC config. All I need to do is provide "/WEB-INF/applicationContext" file path to the "configure" method of Configuration class, but I don't know how find the relative path to this file in JAVA.

```
        public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure(HERE I NEED TO GET "/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml FILE PATH");
            serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                    configuration.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            return sessionFactory;  }
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to fetch a `Spring` configuration file to `Hibernate`? Not sure if that's right...you should probably try to load spring application context using spring configuration and then configure your entity manager factory using spring

Comment: Please, add `applicationContext.xml` to the question. I think, you try to do an incorrect thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate loads `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml` using `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml")`

`ClassLoader` tries to get access to the files in the root of the classpath — for the web-applications it is `war/WEB-INF/classes/`. You should put `applicationContext.xml` to the `war/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml` and load it using

```
sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("applicationContext.xml")
  .buildSessionFactory();
```

You can't specify `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`, because of `/WEB-INF/` is not in the class path.

[How Hibernate loads resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37006444/3405171)

If you really want to get a configuration from `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml` you should get `URL` of `applicationContext.xml` using `ServletContext`: [File path to resource in our war/WEB-INF folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4342095/3405171)

And pass that `URL` to the `Configuration` or `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder`, it depends of Hibernate version.

**An important notice**

I think, above is senseless, because of `applicationContext.xml` should has a structure like `hibernate.cfg.xml` and it, obviously, doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The file should be in your classpath, so you should be able to reference it using the classpath variable: `classpath:/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`

If this won't work then you load the file using class loader and then "ask" for the full path ( this should not be necessary though... ):

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL resource = classLoader.getResource( "WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml" );
String fullPath = resource.getPath()
```

Comment: Neither solution did work....the resource instance of URL class gets NULL, throwing a NullReferenceException.

Comment: The 2nd must have worked...unless the file is not in your classpath

Comment: The file is in WEB-INF folder

Comment: how do I know if its in classpath?

Comment: You can't get access to the `WEB-INF` folder using `ClassLoader`.